# Compile ffmpeg with flascc with network support

Tags: sockets, ffmpeg, flascc

I have compiled ffmpeg with flascc expcept networking. Because flascc cant use sockets,poll and select function. I realized *network.c* file in ffmpeg is a wraper for socket functions. I think socket problem can be solve by writing *network.c* again with flash socktes.

But i have no idea with poll and select. Can i implement poll and select function with flash or can i compile ffmpeg without them.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg can be compiled without linux poll. Run *./configure* and set

```
#define HAVE_STRUCT_POLLFD 0
#define HAVE_POLL_H        0
```

in config.h.

Unfortunately, creating raw sockets from flash sockets seem not possible. Flash have different classes for UDP(Datagram) and TCP(Socket). Also Flash sockets are asynchronous. These problemes can be fix with event listener functions, socket list, flags and while loops. But killer is policy-file-request .Flash socket send this and waiting response. it can solve if you write two side. But it will be fail if you write a client only application. Compiling ffmpeg with network support seem not possible.